# Using the probabilistic method to find number of elements contained in sets?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Let T be a set of size 12, and let $S_1,...,S_{130}$ be 130 subsets of T, each of size 6. Show that there exists a set U of size 3 such that U is contained in at least 12 of the $S_i$. I know to start by picking a random U and compute the expected number of $S_i$ that U is contained in using the indicator method. But I am not sure what to do from there or how to apply the results?

Comment: Not sure how probabilistic methods can help here.  Straight counting though...I mean there are $\binom 63 = 20$ subsets of order $3$ in each set of order $6$...so that means we have $20\times 130=2600$ sets of order $3$ altogether.  Now there are $\binom {12}3=220$ sets of order $3$...if they were each in $11$ or fewer of your chosen sets....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lulu's comment addresses your question well. However, if you stick to a solution which is based on probabilistic methods, below is one.

---

For each subset $S$ of size $3$ of $T$, let $f(S)$ be the # of sets in $\{S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_{130}\}$ that contain $S$. That is,
$$
f(S) = |\{S_i \mid S \subseteq S_i\}|
$$
Note that
$$
\sum_S f(S) = \binom{6}{3} \cdot 130 = 2600
$$
If we sample a $S$ from $T$, then
$$
\mathsf{E}[f(S)] = \frac{2600}{\binom{12}{3}} = \frac{2600}{220} > 11
$$
Therefore, there must exist a $S$ such that $f(S) \geq 12$.

Comment: (+1) But for what you wrote to be correct, I think you want $f(S) := |\{i \mid S \subseteq S_i\}|$, because the $S_i$ are not required to be distinct.